# Convert a replicated list to named list in r

Tags: r

I create named lists manually such as:

```
FD_OesophagitisIntro<-list(x="LA Grade A",
                      x="LA Grade B",
                      x="LA Grade C",
                      x="LA Grade D")
```

but this is repetitive so a neater version is

```
FD_OesophagitisIntro<-list(unique(append(FD_OesophagitisIntro,replicate(4,paste("LA Grade ",sample(c("A","B","C","D"),replace=F))))))
```

however this creates a non named list. How can I create the list above with the neater code

Comment: Did you meant to create the second list from the first? or creating the first list `as.list(setNames(paste("LA Grade", LETTERS[1:4]), rep("x", 4)))`

Comment: So do you need the list to be named? If so, what the names should be? Because giving the same name to each element is a bad idea.

Comment: @Julius I need the names to be the same for use in other functions that I haven't shown so that I can only show the minimal example...

Comment: Ok Sebastian, most of your nested function calls strip names. I believe I've finally unwound it in my answer below. I don't know if this was an exercise to frustrate us, or a real "neater version", but now you have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is how do you use `replicate` to create a named list, you can only do that if the expression has a name.

`replicate` is a wrapper to `sapply` with the expression evaluated as an anonymous function like this:

```
sapply(integer(4), function(...){
    paste("LA Grade ", sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), replace = F)
})
```

There is no `...` argument for `replicate`, but thankfully, `sapply`'s `USE.NAMES` argument is set to `TRUE` by default. So to get names from this, you need to either have `X` be `"character"` (it isn't, it's `"integer"`), or have the return value of `expr` have names.  It isn't. It's the return value of a call to `paste()`, which calls `as.character()` on all it's arguments, so removes attributes, including names. You can see this in the following example:

```
paste(c(a = "x", b = "x"), c(a = "y", b = "y"))
[1] "x y" "x y"
```

This means your solution will involve separating the call to `replicate` out, THEN assigning names to the object it returns. Sadly, it then becomes a fake one-liner with curly braces, or not a one liner at all.

You're also going to have to pass the product of `replicate` to `append` as a list, so that its names are retained, and not use `unique` either (since it strips names).

Here's an example:

```
repd <- replicate(4, paste("LA Grade ", sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), replace = FALSE)))
names(repd) <- rep("x", length(repd))
long <- append(FD_OesophagitisIntro, as.list(repd))
FD_OesophagitisIntro <- long[!duplicated(long)]
names(FD_OesophagitisIntro)
# [1] "x" "x" "x" "x" "x" "x" "x" "x"
```